# Task based file management engine for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to implement task based file management engine. See picture:
[image: (file management engine workflow)]

So, I need to create Transformation Engine and Transformation rules parser. Does something like this already exist?

**UPDATE**

**Input**:  Some files and metadata.

**Output**: Some of input files (maybe all, depends on rules) with another folder structure and file names. Xml files can be transformed with xslt to different text files.

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly, with lot more details on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In terms of existance, yes. In .net... not that I know of. Look for Bonita Studio (open source) or maybe even Talend (also open source)

Comment: I guess this is something like inbox-rules for files? e.g. if you find a file X in your input folder and it's of type jpeg then rename it to X-Y and move it to folder Z?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to map file extensions to folders.

The Scheme would just need to be a mapping table ie ID|FileExtension|Path|FileSuffix

The Engine would just need to be the code that checks the extension and copies the file to the Path whilst adding the FileSuffix to the filename

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

> System.Workflow.Activities

I have used this to have excel style transformation rules with a standard editor from Microsoft.